# Convergence of an irregular integral

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem**: For which choice of $a$ is the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x+4\cos x}{x^{2a}(1+x)}dx$ convergent?

A) 1/2

B) 1/3

C)2/3

D) 3/2

**Attempt**:
The integral can be rewritten as
$$\int\frac{x}{x^{2a}(1+x)} + 4 \int \frac{\cos x}{x^{2a}(1+x)}. $$
Resorting to p-integral or p-series rule, we have to force the power in the denominator to be larger than $1$. For the first integral this leads to
$${2a}-1>1\text{ and }{2a}>1$$
and for the second integral
$$ 2a > 1 \text{ and } 2a+1>1.$$
Taking the intersection of all 4 possible intervals, we arrive at
$a>1/2$ which leads us to choice D.

Spoiler: The solution manual says choice B is the correct answer. I'd appreciate any help to figuring this out.

Comment: Integral can be diverging at $x\to0$: this is not the case of divergency at $x\to\infty$. Second integral with $\cos$ is the most critical one.

Comment: Since $\cos x \sim 1$ as $x\to 0$, the integrand is $\sim \frac{4}{{x^{2a} }}$ as $x\to 0$. Large $x$ are not interesting since we integrate up to $x=1$.